# open every time new Activity using broadcast reciever in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to open an activity using broadcast receiver. I am implement it and it works fine when activity not running in background. But if activity is running in background then it can't launch new activity it return same activity, but i want to open this activity again, means multiple instance of the activity

so, please help me how I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

So you want `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

Refer: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Edit:

Or perhaps, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` . But it's not recommended as it messes with the navigational path of user.